# backbone.js lack of slash before # breaking relative path

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js on client side and express.js on server-side.
The problem is that, with backbone.js routing, the user can either have or have-not a slash before the #, which is breaking relative path in AJAX.

happy path url:

```
localhost:3000/ab/#/cd
// now if
// $.ajax({ "url" : "pay", ... });
// the request url would be
localhost:3000/ab/pay
```

All looks great in the happy path, but...

sad path url:

```
localhost:3000/ab#/cd
// with same AJAX, the request url becomes
localhost:3000/pay
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: only solution i found so far is force redirect with trailing slash, on back-end...is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright dumb question

Since the slash is before the #, it generates a new browser request, and is outside of backbone's control

I can't figure out a way to preserve the relative path, so I just did a force redirect on the backend